# find a very specific tag in soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using BS4 and I have some "soup":

```html
 <TABLE CLASS=MAINBODY WIDTH=100% CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=4 BORDER=1 BORDERCOLOR=#000000><TR><TD>
    <TABLE CLASS=OBJECTNAME WIDTH=100% CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=1><TR><TD WIDTH=44><IMG SRC="foobar.img"></TD><TD>Foobar text</TD></TR></TABLE>
    <!--========== SECTION: FOOBAR DETAILS ==========-->
    <TABLE CLASS=OBJECTNAME HEIGHT=25><TR><TD>Foobar text</TD></TD></TABLE>
    <!--foobar text-->
```

and I want to find the tag:

```html
    <TABLE CLASS=OBJECTNAME WIDTH=100% CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=1><TR><TD WIDTH=44><IMG SRC="foobar.img"></TD><TD>Foobar text</TD></TR></TABLE>
```

I have a list with the string:

```html
 <TD>Foobar text</TD>
```

in it that I am using to search.

How do I find the specific tag without getting the second tag with the same value or get the comment with the same text?

Comment: If I understand you correctyly, you want to search for a `<table>` that contains `<td>` with string `"Foobar text"` ?

Comment: Are you always looking for the first instance of your TD element?

Comment: `soup.find()` returns the first element that matches the criteria, so you won't get the second tag.

Comment: @AndrejKesely that is correct but I only want the first instance and it has to be just that text in a ```<TD>``` in a Table with the ```CLASS=OBJECTNAME```

Comment: I edited the question to show a comment line that I do not want to get back either ```<--foorbar text-->```

Answer (score 0):

after sleeping on it and getting pointed in a better direction by the comments here I found the answer:

assuming a list of strings of tags such as `['<td>foobart text<\td>','<td>foo text<\td>',''<td>bar text<\td>']` named `TagList` is my input here is what I came up with:

```
TagList = ['<td>foobart text<\td>','<td>foo text<\td>',''<td>bar text<\td>']
for i in TagList:
        parentTable = soup.find('td', string=BeautifulSoup(i).text).find_parent('table')
        print(parentTable)
```